# Eclipse sometimes doesn't generate the target-resources folder after building

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, pom.xml

I had added annotation processor in my pom.xml file, it worked properly to generated-resources folder with using terminal outside eclipse but with the terminal inside eclipse, the generated-resources folder sometimes was empty. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <directory>${buildDirectory}</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    <annotationProcessor>com.zenos.core.annotation.processing.PropertyNameAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    <annotationProcessor>com.zenos.core.annotation.processing.JsonSchemaAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <AaddSuppressWarningsAnnotation>true</AaddSuppressWarningsAnnotation>
                    <AjsonSchemaSrc>src/main/resources/com/zenos/json/schema</AjsonSchemaSrc>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Version>${maven.build.timestamp}</Version>
                        <Dependencies>deployment.zenos-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.zenos-ejb.jar, org.infinispan services export</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jar</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Current Eclipse with current Maven? Please tell the version of Eclipse and of Maven that is used in your run configuration (shown in the _Main_ tab at the bottom).

Comment: the eclipse has Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0) and maven is 3.8.1

Comment: [How to reproduce this?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I has just posted the code of pom.xml file.